# How to use github's kadena-io/cardano-crypto.js mnemonic in react native wallet

Tags: javascript, react-native, blockchain, mnemonics, kadena

I want to use github's kadena-io/cardano-crypto.js.This is the cardano-crypto.js Link: **https://github.com/kadena-io/cardano-crypto.js**. But it is an error when used. I've tried a lot to fix the error, but it doesn't work. To get lib.js file in cardano-crypto.js, first I have to install npm. I did that. Then came the lib.js file. Then I tried to import cardano-crypto.js's **mnemonicToRootKeyPair** function to my react-native wallet. But there is an error. To solve the error, first I tried to import cardano-crypto.js with node module. Then I tried to import without node_module. I have imported in several ways.

> import {} from 'path'

,

> _importDefault (require ('path'))

. But somehow Cardano-crypto.js's mnemonicToRootKeyPair could not run/import. Error says lib.js: path could not be found. But the lib.js file is there. Now how do I solve this how to use **mnemonicToRootKeyPair** of cardano-crypto.js in our react native wallet?

This is the cardano-crypto.js **mnemonicToRootKeyPair** function code that I want to use:

```
async function mnemonicToRootKeypair(mnemonic, derivationScheme) {
  validateDerivationScheme(derivationScheme)

  if (derivationScheme === 1) {
    return mnemonicToRootKeypairV1(mnemonic)
  } else if (derivationScheme === 2) {
    return mnemonicToRootKeypairV2(mnemonic, '')
  } else {
    throw Error(`Derivation scheme ${derivationScheme} not implemented`)
  }
}
```

And this is the error when I use the function in my react native wallet:
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve module path from C:\Users\DCL\Desktop\app\cardanoCrypto\lib.js: path could not be found within the project.

Comment: please post the error and the code your trying to implement

Comment: I have mentioned in the post what code I want to use and what kind of error there is. Please check a little.
And this is my react native wallet code that in which I have used the above code:
import {mnemonicToRootKeypair} from '../cardanoCrypto'

function CreateNewWallet({ navigation }) {
    const { walletInfo } = useContext(UserContext);
    const keyPairValue = mnemonicToRootKeypair(walletInfo?.mnemonic, 1);
    console.log(keyPairValue);